# Remove all rows in a df based on condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a multi column filter on a df as below:

```
df_a[(df_a['pages']==0) & (df_a['time']>0)]
```

I want to remove all rows from my df that comply for that filter or remove all rows that return from this df filter as above, how can I tweak code to do this?

Comment: Your condition looks good. What's the error?

Comment: no error, the question was  how to remove all the rows from a df that this condition returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `negation operator(~)`:

```
df_a[~((df_a['pages']==0) & (df_a['time']>0))]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret what you are saying correctly, you want what shows up in your filter above to be excluded. try this.

```
df_a[(df_a['pages']!=0) & (df_a['time']<=0)]
```

Comment: I tried this and it returns 0 rows which is not correct